# How to upload dynamically generated PDF to AWS with Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, pdf-generation, dompdf

I am dynamically generating a PDF with DOMPDF in Laravel and I have to save the document to Amazon's Cloud service.

I am unable to save the document to the cloud. But I can only save locally.

```
 $pdf = PDF::loadView('contract.contract-pdf', $ data);
 $pdf->save('contract.pdf');
 $s3 =\Storage::disk('s3');
 $s3->put('pdf/contract', new File('contract.pdf'), 'public');
```

How to send it to cloud?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can do like that

**put pdf output(content) on storage**

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('contract.contract-pdf', $data);
 \Storage::disk('s3')->put('pdf/contract.pdf', $pdf->output(), 'public');
```

Comment: hello there, in put('pdf/contract.pdf', $pdf->output());
what is 'pdf/contract.pdf', is it the path to something?

Comment: @elvis-chuks 'pdf/contract.pdf' is a path

Comment: @elvis-chuks It gives "Call to a member function output on string". Also used stream() function. It gives Call to a member function stream() on string. Any suggestions what can be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

After you have saved the file on your server, You'd need to call `putObject` API on the instance of `Aws\S3\S3Client` `$s3`

```
$result = $s3->putObject([
'Bucket' => '-- bucket name --',
'Key'    => $key,
'Body'   => 'this is the body!',
'SourceFile' => '/path/to/the/file.png'
]);
```

For more: https://medium.com/@kentaguilar/simplest-way-to-upload-a-file-to-aws-s3-via-php-e83a9f54ba77